# Adding a custom design to ActiveAdmin - rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, admin

I'm trying to add this template to active admin on my rails app

http://themeforest.net/item/wintermin-bootstrap-admin-theme/8447093?WT.ac=category_item&WT.z_author=geedmo

But for the life of me, I can't work out where to do it. Has anyone had experience in completing something like this before?

If so, where do i start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update

I've created a GitHub project where you can see all open-source themes available for Active Admin. **[Check out](https://github.com/paladini/activeadmin-themes)**.

---

I know that the question has almost 2 years, but the first (and accepted) answer doesn't seems to provide enough information. ActiveAdmin already has some custom styles / themes that you can easily integrate with your project. You can start from one of these themes (forking it) and making the needed changes to achieve what you want.

## Here's some nice themes for ActiveAdmin:

**[Active Material](https://github.com/vigetlabs/active_material)**
[image]

**[Active Skin](https://github.com/rstgroup/active_skin)**
[image]

**[Active Admin Theme](https://github.com/activeadmin-plugins/active_admin_theme)**
[image]

If one of these themes seems okay to you and you don't want to change it, just integrate one of them into your project (it's very easy, as you can read in their documentation).

Comment: How to install our own theme. Let say I have metronic admin theme then how to install it??

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the theme, it will be bootstrap with some custom styles.

You need to have bootstrap requested somewhere (i.e a bootstrap for rails type gem, or use CDN) and also include the custom CSS from this theme.

What you then do with it is up to you - it won't magically pop up looking like that unless you have all the same html/erb that is running that demo.